# WebStorm "Run 'index.html'" not working on remote project

Tags: webstorm

I use **Run 'index.html'** a lot in WebStorm. It allows me to run my application on a mini webserver locally on my computer.

However, I have a project that has a connection to a FTP host (my eventual destination for my web files).

When I have this connection in my project settings and I Run 'index.html' the browser opens at : `wwww.example.com/index.html`, instead of `http://localhost:1234/index.html`.

How do I tell WebStorm to run locally? Do I have to delete all my FTP connection settings every time I want to test something locally?

Comment: When you are using `Open in browser` and similar actions -- iDE uses URL from current Deployment entry (which is marked as Default) to build full URL. If you have no deployment entries defined then built-in web server is used instead.

Comment: So .. the solution would be: 1) create new deployment entry of `In Place` type (so no files get copied anywhere), 2) configure it (URL etc) 3) mark it as Default for this project. Now, when you need to use your `wwww.example.com/` kind of URLs, you can mark another deployment entry as default. Since this FTP entry is no longer Default .. instead of `Upload to XXX` you would use `Upload to...` which will show you the list of available servers (yeap, 1 extra moment/key press)

Comment: Alternative (and definitely better) solution would be using actual Run/Debug Configurations (`Run | Edit Configurations...`) where you can hard code the actual URL so it will be used regardless of your current deployment settings. Once created, such entries available via drop down box on main toolbar (next to Run/Debug buttons)

Answer (score 0):

Just as @LazyOne mentioned, when your have a default webserver configured in Deployment preferences, it is used for previewing instead of the built-in server; the best solution is using Run configuration with the built-in server URL for running your application. But, as run configurations created from right-click menu always have the default server URL pre-configured, you need to edit created configurations in Run/Edit configurations dialog.
BTW, there is a feature request to optionally use built-in webserver for previewing files in browser regardless of deployment settings, [WEB-18958](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18958). Please vote for it to be notified on any progress